# Need to replace drug code with name of drug EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an  (1) excel sheet with drug codes and a (2) second sheet with drug code to drug name identifation. I need to replace the drug codes in first sheet with the drug names in the second sheet.

first sheet with codes (1)
[image: first sheet with codes]

second sheet with codes and drug names (2)
[image]

What is the formula to put in the first sheet (column M perhaps) that would find the drug name in the other sheet and enter it in?

Comment: You need the `VLookup()` worksheet function for this.

Comment: Thank you, I used VLookup() but decided to use index instead.

Comment: Does that mean you used vlookup or index?

Comment: index was better

Answer (score 0):

Use `Index()` and `Match()` function together in `M` column. See below.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!A:A,0))
```